# How would I trim a number to 5 digits in PHP?

Tags: php, trim, number-formatting

I have a number like this:

```
12345678987654321
```

I want to only use the first 5 digits like this:

```
12345
```

How would I do that in PHP? `number_format`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like `substr($number, 0, 5);` would suffice.

Answer (score 5):

```
$num = "12345678987654321";
$num2 = substr($num, 0, 5);
```